# File upload problems in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, upload

[here is an upload button, from which user can choose the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Vxi.png)

Basically what I want to do is whenever user chooses an image from that, 
it should display it at the place where that "trees" image is.

I'm stuck, really need some help.

here is the code

```html
<div class="user-editable-div"> 
  <div class="image-div" id="image_div"><img src="images/image.jpg" id="bg_image" /></div>
  <span class="upload-btn">UPLOAD IMAGE</span>
  <input type="file" id="uploader" />
  <div class="content-div">
   <h1 contenteditable="true">USER EDITABLE</h1>
   <p contenteditable="true">All elements on this page are user editable. You can edit them by simply clicking or by clicking on the edit button next to the element.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

when the user chooses a file from "#uploader" it should display the image in "#bg_image"

Comment: you use ajax() or post() or get()  or you just doing that with php??

Comment: I'm a beginner so don't know much, using jquery, I don't want the page to reload, I just want if user chooses a file it should display on the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With this code when you try to upload image with use file controller at that time that image preview in bg_image element**

```
   <div class="user-editable-div">  
        <div class="image-div" id="image_div"><img src="images/image.jpg" id="bg_image" /></div>
        <span class="upload-btn">UPLOAD IMAGE</span>
        <input type="file" id="uploader" onchange="readURL(this,this.id);"/>
        <div class="content-div">
            <h1 contenteditable="true">USER EDITABLE</h1>
            <p contenteditable="true">
              All elements on this page are user editable. You can edit them by simply clicking or by clicking on the edit button next to the element.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

   <script>
function readURL(input,ids)
{
    if (input.files && input.files[0])
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e)
            {
                $('#bg_image').attr('src', e.target.result).width(650).height(375);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
}       
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching `change` event to `input type="file"` element , using `URL.createObjectURL()` with argument `this.files[0]` within `change` handler to set `src` of `img` with `.attr(attribute, value)`

```js
$(":file").change(function(e) {
  $("#bg_image").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]))
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-editable-div"> 
  <div class="image-div" id="image_div"><img id="bg_image"src="" /></div>
  <span class="upload-btn">UPLOAD IMAGE</span>
  <input type="file" id="uploader" accept="image/*" />
  <div class="content-div">
   <h1 contenteditable="true">USER EDITABLE</h1>
   <p contenteditable="true">All elements on this page are user editable. You can edit them by simply clicking or by clicking on the edit button next to the element.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```